# What is the alternate solution for AddMediatR in the .NET Core Web API Program.CS file?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, cqrs, mediatr

I'm creating a application called "Employee Salary Management System", using CQRS and MediatR so when I add this below line on the Program.cs file then I got and compilation error so how could I fix it,

```
builder.Services.AddMediatR(typeof(ApplicationContext).Assembly);
```

I tried to addMediatR on the Program.cs file for work with mediatr for implemeting CQRS pattern but i can't able to add this line on my program.cs file so how could I solve this error

.NET Version is 8.0

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using t1.Context;
using MediatR;
using System.Reflection; // Add this for Assembly
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
        b => b.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(ApplicationContext).Assembly.FullName)));

// Register MediatR with the assembly containing your request handlers

builder.Services.AddMediatR(typeof(ApplicationContext).Assembly);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: Please always include the error message. We can’t guess what it is or what is wrong.